# Keep Samsung apps/"features" after rooting?

Tags: custom-roms, root-access, samsung, rom, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I know that if I root my samsung phone, I will lose a lot of Samsung features (like fingerprint scanner probably, and apps like S Note etc). And I understand that its the base that a rom is created on which determines if it can support things like that (I think?), but is there any way I can use a custom rom and still keep Samsung features, especially things like gestures and the customizations/settings screen from my S5? OR 'import' those features back in onto Cyanogenmod or something similar?

I want the best of both worlds, and can't seem to find any answers

Comment: Rooting and installing a custom ROM are different (but related) things. Do you actually want Cyanogenmod, or do you just want to root the phone?

Comment: @DanHulme I want a custom rom with the touchwiz features I think

Answer (score 2):

Rooting your phone (standard rooting procedure; not from flashing a custom ROM) will not make you lose Samsung features.

If you flash CyanogenMod (which is a custom ROM that also has root pre-installed), you will no longer be able to use Samsung's features. Samsung is Touchwhiz-based (TW), and CyanogenMod is AOSP-based. Apps developed only for TW-based ROMs are not compatible with AOSP-based ROMs.

Comment: Riight I think thats what I was looking for. So I think I just need a TW based rom?

Comment: @user60251 Yes, you need a TW-based ROM if you want to use/install Samsung features.